# How do I make an executable file from an intellij idea project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, google-api, google-calendar-api

I created a gradle project in Intellij idea. After building and running everything worked as  expected. But I don't want to run an IDE everytime I need to use my program. Can anyone recommend a step-by- step guide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can quickly do it in IntelliJ following theses steps :

- Go to File > Project Structure
- Select Artifacts tab and click on the "+" icon
- Choose to generate a JAR from modules with dependencies
- Choose your module and its main class and save changes
- Now go to Build > build artifacts > **build***

It's done, your executable `.jar` file should be located in `out/artifacts/module_name/module.jar`

*****Choose rebuild if it has already been built.

Comment: In addition, I also had to add the manifest file and my credentials to the jar archive to make everything work.